# Difference between pre-trained word embedding and training word embedding in keras

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, deep-learning

I am new to Deep Learning and I want to explore Deep Learning for NLP. I went through word embeddings and tested them in gensim word2vec. I also heard about pre-trained models. I am confused about the difference between pre-trained models and training the model yourself, and how to use the results.

I want to apply it in keras because I do not want to write formulas and all in Theano or Tensorflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When training word2vec with gensim, the result you achieve is a representation of the words in your vocabulary as vectors. The dimension of these vectors is the size of the neural network.

The pre-trained word2vec models simply contain a list of those vectors that were pre-trained on a large corpus. You will find pre-trained vectors of various sizes.

How to use those vector representations? That depends on what you want to do. Some interesting properties have been shown for these vectors: it has been shown that the vector for 'man' + 'king' - 'woman' will often result in the closest match to the vector 'woman'. You may also consider using the word vectors as input for another neural network/computation model.

Gensim is a very optimized library to perform the CBOW and skip-gram algorithms but if you really want to set up your neural network yourself, you will first have to learn about the structure of CBOW and skip-gram and learn how to code it in keras for example. This should not be particularly complex and a google search for these subjects should provide you with many results to help you along.